# the function of the head of a linked list

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I don't know what is the function of the linked list header, does it contain data, or just to point to the first item in the list?

sometimes I found some resources stock data in the head, more than that this code on geeks4geeks

```
    /* 3. Make next of new node as head */
    new_node->next = (*head_ref);
   
    /* 4. move the head to point to the new node */
    (*head_ref)    = new_node;
```

I don't understand it well

Comment: `head_ref` is just a pointer to a node.  The node can have data and a next pointer.    So you treat the head the same way as the next pointer.

Comment: The process adds an item to the head of the list (so it will be in reverse order). The previous head pointed to the start of the list (or was `NULL` in the case of the first insertion). When you iterate the linked list, each node points to the next node, or is `NULL` for the last item. If the head is `NULL` the list is empty.

Comment: You probably should use pencil & paper to draw what is happening. Don't confuse the pointer to the head node (it's just a pointer; possibly NULL) with the actual head node itself. Those are two separate entities...

Answer (score 1):

`head_ref` is a `Node**`, which is to say that `*head_ref` (which I also called `head` below) is a `Node*`. A `Node*` is a pointer to a node, and `*head_ref` is specifically a pointer to the first node of the list.

```
Node **head_ref     Node *head          Node anon1                Node anon0
                    @ 0x1000            @ 0x3000                  @ 0x2000
+-----------+       +-----------+       +-----------------+       +-----------------+
| 0x1000 ---------->| 0x3000 ---------->| next: 0x2000 ---------->| next: NULL      |
+-----------+       +-----------+       | data: ...       |       | data: ...       |
                                        +-----------------+       +-----------------+
```

The code you have there is executed after creating a new node.

```
Node **head_ref     Node *head                                    Node anon1
                    @ 0x1000                                      @ 0x3000
+-----------+       +-----------+                                 +-----------------+
| 0x1000 ---------->| 0x3000 ------------------------------------>| next: ...       |
+-----------+       +-----------+                                 | data: ...       |
                                                                  +-----------------+

                    Node *new_node      Node anon2
                                        @ 0x4000
                    +-----------+       +-----------------+
                    | 0x4000 ---------->| next: NULL      |
                    +-----------+       | data: ...       |
                                        +-----------------+
```

After `new_node->next = (*head_ref);`:

```
Node **head_ref     Node *head                                    Node anon1
                    @ 0x1000                                      @ 0x3000
+-----------+       +-----------+                                 +-----------------+
| 0x1000 ---------->| 0x3000 ---------------------------------+-->| next: ...       |
+-----------+       +-----------+                             |   | data: ...       |
                                                              |   +-----------------+
                                                              |
                    Node *new_node      Node anon2            |
                                        @ 0x4000              |
                    +-----------+       +-----------------+   |
                    | 0x4000 ---------->| next: 0x3000 -------+
                    +-----------+       | data: ...       |
                                        +-----------------+
```

After `(*head_ref) = new_node;`

```
Node **head_ref     Node *head                                    Node anon1
                    @ 0x1000                                      @ 0x3000
+-----------+       +-----------+                                 +-----------------+
| 0x1000 ---------->| 0x4000 -------+                         +-->| next: ...       |
+-----------+       +-----------+   |                         |   | data: ...       |
                                    |                         |   +-----------------+
                                    |                         |
                    Node *new_node  |   Node anon2            |
                                    |   @ 0x4000              |
                    +-----------+   |   +-----------------+   |
                    | 0x4000 -------+-->| next: 0x3000 -------+
                    +-----------+       | data: ...       |
                                        +-----------------+
```

But what if the list is empty? Then `*head_ref` starts off containing NULL, and you end up with

```
Node **head_ref     Node *head
                    @ 0x1000
+-----------+       +-----------+
| 0x1000 ---------->| 0x4000 -------+
+-----------+       +-----------+   |
                                    |
                                    |
                    Node *new_node  |   Node anon2
                                    |   @ 0x4000
                    +-----------+   |   +-----------------+
                    | 0x4000 -------+-->| next: NULL      |
                    +-----------+       | data: ...       |
                                        +-----------------+
```

Perfect!

(All addresses are completely fictional, of course.)